# Find the distance between two lat-lon position in Kilometre using awk

Tags: awk, location, distance

I would like to calculate distance between two stations (behind and ahead) from the middle station. Each station has a GPS location. For example:

```
P1      20.2    70
P2      21      70.3
P3      21.5    70.4
P4      22      71
P5      22.75   71.6
P6      23      72
P7      23.2    72.4
P8      24      73.3
P9      24.5    74
P10     25.1    74.3
```

Here each P in the 1st column is the station name of a particular station and have the latitudinal and longitudinal location in 2nd and 3rd columns respectively.

I would like to compute the distance of each station from its ahead one and behind one i.e.

```
For P2 what is the distance between P1 and P3 in KM?
For P3 What is the distance between P2 and P4 in KM?
For P4 what is the distance between P3 and P5 in KM?
........
........
For P9 what is the distance between P8 and P10 in KM?
```

The desired output looks like:

```
P2      149.62
P3      134.27
P4      190.60
P5      155.56
P6      100.97
P7      180.41
P8      226.77
P9      163.53
```

I computed the distance using the following formula and I was not sure whether it was correct one to use in GPS based location.

```
d = sqrt(pow(lat2-lat1, 2) + pow(lon2-lon1, 2))
```

I was writing an `awk` code for the above, and facing problem. Karafa (See the answer) helped to write an `awk` script as per my demand. Which was

```
awk ' {k[NR] = $1
         a[NR] = $2
         b[NR] = $3}
    END {for(i=2; i<NR; i++)
           print k[i], (sqrt((a[i+1]-a[i-1])^2 + (b[i+1]-b[i-1])^2))*110}' file.txt
```

It worked perfectly fine, however, after getting a comment from Dawg (see the comments), I realised that Haversine formulae will be the correct method to follow, which I am coping from here https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#AWK .

```
# syntax: GAWK -f HAVERSINE_FORMULA.AWK
# converted from Python
BEGIN {
    distance(36.12,-86.67,33.94,-118.40) # BNA to LAX
    exit(0)
}
function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,  a,c,dlat,dlon) {
    dlat = radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = radians(lon2-lon1)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a))
    printf("distance: %.4f km\n",6372.8 * c)
}
function radians(degree) { # degrees to radians
    return degree * (3.1415926 / 180.)
}
```

Now I would like to update the solution with the above Haversine formula. I am doing it as below, but getting many syntax errors:

```
awk ' {k[NR] = $1
             a[NR] = $2
             b[NR] = $3}
        END {for(i=2; i<NR; i++)
    function distance(a[i-1],b[i-1],a[i+1],b[i+1],  a,c,dlat,dlon) {
        dlat = radians(a[i+1]-a[i-1])
        dlon = radians(b[i+1]-b[i-1])
        lat1 = radians(a[i-1])
        lat2 = radians(a[i+1])
        a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a))
        #printf("distance: %.4f km\n",6372.8 * c)  #I have disabled it
    }
    function radians(degree) { # degrees to radians
        return degree * (3.1415926 / 180.)
    }
               print k[i], 6372.8 * c}' file.txt
```

Comment: This might help: [Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: In your `END` block, you refer to $1, which is the first field of the LAST line, because it is the END-block!

Comment: The function `pow()` does not exist in awk. The existing functions are listed here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html

Comment: BTW, in your END block you also refer to `$j` ?????,,  i would say back to the drawing board...!

Comment: You can use the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate the great circle distances between given Lat / Lon pairs. [HERE](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#AWK) is an `awk` implementation.

Comment: @dawg Many thanks. It is extremely useful. I will follow it.

Comment: If you plug your lat/lon pairs in [THIS](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml) calculator, you can see that there are issues with your input data. The distance `P1->P2` is 94 km...

Comment: @dawg distance is for P1-P3 is computed.  It's matching 150km.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will fix your `awk` issues with minimal changes, but for distance you're using Euclidean norm, which is not valid on spheres but will be good approximate for short distances.

```
$ awk ' {k[NR] = $1
         a[NR] = $2
         b[NR] = $3}
    END {for(i=2; i<NR; i++)
           print k[i], sqrt((a[i+1]-a[i-1])^2 + (b[i+1]-b[i-1])^2)}' file

P2 1.36015
P3 1.22066
P4 1.73277
P5 1.41421
P6 0.917878
P7 1.64012
P8 2.06155
P9 1.48661
```

Not sure what kind of scaling you're using.
For example for P2

```
dist^2 = (21.5-20.2)^2 + (70.4-70)^2 = 1.3^2 + 0.4^2 = 1.69 + 0.16 = 1.85 = (1.36)^2
```

For using a spherical surface distance based on degrees, just plug in the right distance function

```
$ awk 'function distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,  a,c,dlat,dlon) {
         dlat = radians(lat2-lat1)
         dlon = radians(lon2-lon1)
         lat1 = radians(lat1)
         lat2 = radians(lat2)
         a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
         c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a),sqrt(1-a))
         return 6372.8 * c}
      function radians(degree) {return degree * (3.1415926 / 180.)}  
        {k[NR] = $1
         a[NR] = $2
         b[NR] = $3}
    END {for(i=2; i<NR; i++)
           print k[i], distance(a[i+1],b[i+1],a[i-1],b[i-1])}' file


P2 150.453
P3 132.736
P4 186.056
P5 151.428
P6 96.0023
P7 173.071
P8 217.711
P9 158.759
```

Comment: @karafa. Would it be possible to edit your answer. I have update my question. I realised that the euclidean formula may not give the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks. It worked. I understood my mistakes also.